# sharepoint2007 installation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to install sharepoint 2007 in my PC. Before installation of sharepoint 2007 server, what are the requirements and after having all the requirements, what are the steps to install in  my PC.

Regards,
Abhimanyu

Answer (score 2):

Find the detailed installation guide of SharePoint 2007 on a system [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2007/03/28/how-to-install-sharepoint-server-2007-on-a-single-machine.aspx)

or you can use SharePoint 2007 VHD (available on microsoft site) and integrate via Virtual PC tool on your machine having XP, Vista OS (not a server OS 2003 or higher).

Answer (score 0):

The first requirement is that you are running an actual Windows Server, not a PC. After that you need to decide if you are going to use a full SQL Server 2005 installation or the free express version. User authentication should also be considered before beginning: will you be using Active Directory, some other directory services or forms based authentication with your own user database?

I suggest you try the MS sites for more details and best practices. This is a good place to start: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288005%28office.12%29.aspx